# Unique solution for IVP with $y''(x) + y(x)^2 = 0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I'm supposed to show that the following initial value problem has a unique non-trivial solution.

- $y''(x) + y(x)^2 = 0$
- $y(0) = y(1) = 0$

My approach so far is:

$$y''(x) = -y(x)^2 \Rightarrow y^{-2}dy^2 = -dx^2 \Rightarrow (-y^{-1} + c_1)dy = -c_2 dx \Rightarrow \ln{|y|} + c_1 y = c_2 x + c_3$$

Here is the problem, if we say $y(0) = 0$ but I try to plug that in, I need to calculate $\ln{(0)}$ which is not defined. Did I mess this up?

Comment: Yeah, it is correct. It is problem 1.26 on page 30 here (https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~gerald/ftp/book-ode/ode.pdf). What do you mean? Is my approach not correct?

Comment: No, your alchemy with differential quotients is not correct. The second order derivative is not the square of the first order derivative. Multiply with $2y'$ and integrate to get $y'^2+\frac23y^3=C$.

Comment: @Moo maybe there is a way to show there is a unique solution without explicitly solving it?

Comment: @LutzLehmann I'm not sure I understand what you are referring to as "alchemy". I know I wrote it as $dy^2$ and $dx^2$ but that was just so I could integrate twice. Which step exactly is wrong?

Comment: If we remain informal, the numerator of the second derivative is $d^2y=y(x+dx)-2y(x)+y(x-dx)$ while the square of the first derivative is in the numerator $(dy)^2=(y(x+dx)-y(x))^2$. Or did you mean $d(y^2)=y(x+dx)^2-y(x)^2$?

Comment: Okay, so if I'm more careful I can write:

$$d^2 y/ dx^2 = -y^2 \Rightarrow d^2 y = -y^2 dx^2 \Rightarrow d^2 y/y^2 = -dx^2 \Rightarrow \int{y^{-2}d^2y = -\int{dx^2}} \Rightarrow 
 -y^{-1} dy = (-x + c)dx$$

My guess is that my error is in the last step?

Comment: Yes, the last step. Such an integration does not exist. Just like $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is a symbol with a suggestive structure and many rules for its correct use, so is $\int ... dx$ in the first place a suggestive symbol and associated rules. That the rules sometimes harmonize very well with the symbolic makes them easier to learn, but also easier to abuse.

Answer (score 1):

The argument roughly goes as follows: Choose a unique solution $y$ such that $y(0)=0$ and $y'(0)=1$. This is possible because of Picard-Lindelöf theorem. Prove by differentiating the LHS (so it is constant) that the energy equation
$$
\frac{1}{2}(y')^2 + \frac{1}{3}y^3 = \frac{1}{2}
$$
holds. Because of $y$ increasing near zero, it must hold because of the above equation that $y'$ decreases and $y$ increases until $y'(\bar x) = 0$ for some $\bar x >0$ with positive value (according to the above equation).

Here, $y$ has a local maximum: Since a piecewise constant solution is impossible according to $y''+y^2=0$, $y$ can only decrease there: If it were to increase, then the energy equation is clearly violated. So in $\bar x$, $y'$ decreases again, gets negative and the energy equation states that $y'$ has to decrease further if $y$ decreases as well. This happens until $y(\hat{x})=0$ for some $0 < \bar x < \hat{x}$ (and even further). Then prove that the mapping
$$
v(x) := \hat{x}^2 y\left(\hat{x}\cdot x \right)
$$
is still a solution to the BVP. $v$ is of course non-trivial.